# update dplyr, Error in dplyr::select_vars

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Error in dplyr::select_vars(colnames(data), ...) : 
  could not find function "tidy_quotes"

the above error appears when I updated dplyr using 
this:

```
if (packageVersion("devtools") < 1.6) {
  install.packages("devtools")
}
devtools::install_github("hadley/lazyeval")
devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")
```

The above error appears when I tried to use dplyr or tidyr

Not sure how to solve this problem. Please help. I am using RStudio in Ubuntu14.

Comment: dplyr is in the process of switching its NSE system to a broader fork of lazyeval called [rlang](https://github.com/hadley/rlang) which you may need to install as well if you're trying to run the development version. Or just install the CRAN version, which is easier to install and more stable.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're facing issues in installing the dplyr package. Better remove both the packages plyr and dplyr and then try again installing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try this try the following command to select variables in dplyr:

```
df <- df %>%
select(c(var1, var2, var3))
```

I usually have trouble with select_vars